# Calculating number of SKUs present in both the years in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

```
Outlet_C  SKUs  Year    GSV
---------------------------
Outlet 1    A   2018    100
Outlet 1    B   2018    200
Outlet 1    C   2018    300
Outlet 1    D   2018    400
Outlet 1    E   2018    100
Outlet 1    F   2018    200
Outlet 1    A   2019    200
Outlet 1    B   2019    300
Outlet 1    G   2019    500
Outlet 1    H   2019    200
```

Need to develop a DAX query to find number of SKUs which are Repeated(AB), Lost(present in 2018 but not in 2019: CDE) and New(present in 2019 but not in 2018: GH) for a selected outlet code.

My futile attempt:

```
Repeated_Count = Calculate(DistinctCount(Table1[SKUs]), 
             filter(Table1, Table1[GSV]>0 && Table1[Year] = "2018",
             filter(Table1, Table1[GSV]>0 && Table1[Year] = "2019"))
```

Please let me know the correct approach. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This DAX query will produce the desired output.

```
EVALUATE CALCULATETABLE(
    VAR _SummaryTable = ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE( Table1, Table1[SKUs] ),
        "2018", CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( Table1 ), Table1[Year] = 2018 ),
        "2019", CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( Table1 ), Table1[Year] = 2019 )
    )
    RETURN ROW(
        "Repeated",
        SUMX( _SummaryTable, ( [2018] > 0 ) * ( [2019] > 0 ) ),
        "Lost",
        SUMX( _SummaryTable, ( [2018] > 0 ) * ( [2019] = 0 ) ),
        "New",
        SUMX( _SummaryTable, ( [2018] = 0 ) * ( [2019] > 0 ) )
    ),
    Table1[Outlet_C] = "Outlet 1"
)
```